# perl hdb debugger: browser displays UTF-8 source code in wrong encoding

Tags: html, perl, debugging, utf-8

My Perl source code contains UTF-8 stuff like this

```perl
# Einige Konstanten für reguläre Ausdrücke, um die Lesbarkeit zu
# erhöhen.
my $Marker = qr/[.·<>=-]/x;
my $Buchstabe = qr/(?: [^.·<>=-] | ch)/x;
my $Vokal = qr/[aeiouäëïöüy]/x;
# Konsonant: nicht Vokal, aber Buchstabe.
my $Konsonant = qr/(?! $Vokal ) $Buchstabe/x;
```

However, the hdb debugger browser window shows the code as latin1 encoded:

[image: hdb output]

Looking into the HTML source code I see that it is properly encoded in UTF-8; this means that somewhere from Perl's debugging interface to the HTML page a wrong encoding gets used.

Note that `perl -d` works just fine and displays the source code correctly in my GNU/Linux KDE terminal.

How can I fix that?  Is there a configuration file?  Is this a bug?  I'm using `Devel::hdb` version 0.25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is a missing `decode_utf8()` at [line 27](https://metacpan.org/release/BRUMMETT/Devel-hdb-0.25/source/lib/Devel/hdb/App/SourceFile.pm#L27):

```
@rv = map { [ $_, $_ + 0 ] } @$file;
```

if I change this line to

```
@rv = map { [ decode_utf8($_), $_ + 0 ] } @$file;
```

and import `decode_utf8` from [Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) before that, I get this output:

[image]